# Symfony2 undefined offset: 0 error with lottery project

Tags: php, symfony

In my lottery project I have 5 tickets, in which you select numbers and buy. The thing is, you can only buy the tickets if you buy them in order... For example:

```
Ticket 1    Ticket 2    Ticket 3   Ticket 4   Ticket 5
```

If you add numbers to the ticket 1 and then the others it works... If you skip the ticket 1 and add numbers to the other ones, when you try to buy you get this error:

ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\Digidis\front\src\MediaparkLt\UserBundle\Service\MoneyManager.php line 313

The full stack:

```
array('cartProduct' => array('title' => 'EUROMILLONES', 'price' => '2.35', 'product' => '2', 'ticket_id' => '1433921783_19792', 'numbers' => '8,13,14,17,37', 'stars' => '4,7', 'betslip' => '{"duration":"1","subscription":"false","jsPrice":"235","type":"simple","numbers1":"0,0,0,0,0","numbers2":"8,13,14,17,37","numbers3":"0,0,0,0,0","numbers4":"0,0,0,0,0","numbers5":"0,0,0,0,0","stars1":"0,0","stars2":"4,7","stars3":"0,0","stars4":"0,0","stars5":"0,0","dayOfWeek":"3"}', 'is_syndicate' => false, 'draw' => object(DateTime)), 'product' => object(Product), 'user' => object(User), 'reference' => null, 'paymentResult' => 'Authorised', 'bets' => object(stdClass), 'individualBets' => array(), 'tickets' => array(array('numbers' => '8,13,14,17,37', 'stars' => '4,7')), 'k' => '0', 't' => array('numbers' => '0,0,0,0,0', 'stars' => '0,0'), 'is_ticket_filled' => false, 'week_id' => array(array('ticketId' => '7005')), 'g' => '0', 'lastId' => '7005', 'purchase' => object(Purchase), 'price' => '2.35', 'bet' => object(Bet), 'euromillonesBet' => object(EuromillonesBet), 'drawDate' => array(object(DrawDate)), 'j' => '0')) in C:\wamp\www\Digidis\front\src\MediaparkLt\UserBundle\Service\MoneyManager.php line 313
```

As you can see first it gets the ticket 1, which is empty(or 0) and thats why it causes the error... How can I make it so that it skips the empty tickets?

Here is the controller where the error occurs:

```
$bets = json_decode($cartProduct['betslip']);

        $individualBets = array();

        $tickets = array(
            array('numbers' => $bets->numbers1, 'stars' => $bets->stars1),
            array('numbers' => $bets->numbers2, 'stars' => $bets->stars2),
            array('numbers' => $bets->numbers3, 'stars' => $bets->stars3),
            array('numbers' => $bets->numbers4, 'stars' => $bets->stars4),
            array('numbers' => $bets->numbers5, 'stars' => $bets->stars5)
        );

        if ($bets->type === 'simple') {
            foreach ($tickets as $k => $t) {
                $is_ticket_filled = ((int) str_replace(',', '', $t['numbers'])) > 0;
                if (!$is_ticket_filled) {
                    unset($tickets[$k]);
                }
            }
        } else if ($bets->type === 'multiple') {
            $tickets = array(array('numbers' => $bets->numbers1, 'stars' => $bets->stars1));
        }

        $week_id = null;
        for ($k = 0; $k < (count($tickets)); $k++) {
            for ($g = 0; $g < $bets->duration; $g++) {
                if (!isset($week_id[$g])) {
                    $week_id[$g] = $this->entityManager->getRepository('MediaparkLtLotteryBundle:Bet')->getLastTicketId();

                    if ($week_id[$g]) {
                        $week_id[$g]['ticketId'] ++;
                    } else {
                        $week_id[$g]['ticketId'] = 0;
                    }
                }

                $lastId = $week_id[$g]['ticketId'];

                $purchase = new Purchase();
                $purchase->setUser($user);
                $purchase->setDrawDate($cartProduct['draw']);
                $purchase->setProduct($product);
                $purchase->setReference($reference);
                $price = $cartProduct['price'];

                $bet = new Bet();

                if ('eurojackpot' == $product->getAlias()) {
                    $euromillonesBet = new EurojackpotBet();
                } else {
                    $euromillonesBet = new EuromillonesBet();
                }

                $drawDate = $this->entityManager->getRepository('MediaparkLtLotteryBundle:DrawDate')->findByDrawDate($cartProduct['draw']);
                if (!$drawDate)
                    die('no draw date found ' . $cartProduct['draw']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

                $bet->setDrawDate($drawDate[0]);
                $bet->setTicketId($lastId);

                if (strtoupper($paymentResult) === 'AUTHORISED') {
                    $bet->setStatus(BetStatus::AUTHORISED);
                } else {
                    $bet->setStatus(BetStatus::FAILED);
                }

                $bet->setWinnings(0);

                $euromillonesBet->setBet($bet);
/// LINE 313 ABOVE!!!!!!!
                $numbers = $this->getNumbersArray($tickets[$k]['numbers']);

                $j = 0;
                foreach ($numbers as $number) {
                    $j++;
                    $name = 'setN' . $j;
                    $euromillonesBet->$name($number);
                }

                $numbers = $this->getNumbersArray($tickets[$k]['stars']);
                $euromillonesBet->setS1($numbers[0]);
                $euromillonesBet->setS2($numbers[1]);

                $euromillonesBet->setAmountOfStars(Bet::NUMBER_OF_STARS);

                $purchase->addBet($bet);

                $purchase->setPricePaid($price);

                if (strtoupper($paymentResult) === 'AUTHORISED') {
                    $purchase->setStatus(PaymentStatus::AUTHORISED);
                } else {
                    $purchase->setStatus(PaymentStatus::FAILED);
                }

                if ($bets->subscription === "true") {
                    $contract = new PurchaseContract();
                    $contract->setAccumulatedWinnings(0);
                    $contract->setCancellationDate(null);
                    $contract->setFirstDrawDate($purchase->getDrawDate());
                    $contract->setLastRenewedDate($purchase->getDrawDate());
                    $contract->setNextRenewalFirstDrawDate($purchase->getDrawDate());
                  //  $contract->setPurchase($purchase);
                    $contract->setStatusPurchaseContract(1);
                    $contract->setWeeks(1);
                    $purchase->setPurchaseContract($contract);
                    $this->entityManager->persist($contract);

                }

                if ($g == 0)
                    $individualBets[] = $euromillonesBet;

                $this->entityManager->persist($bet);
                $this->entityManager->persist($euromillonesBet);
                $this->entityManager->persist($purchase);

                $this->entityManager->flush();
            }
        }
        return $individualBets;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see the bet type in your object is set to `"type":"simple"` and `numbers1":"0,0,0,0,0"`

```
$is_ticket_filled = ((int) str_replace(',', '', $t['numbers'])) > 0;
//(int) 00000 = 0
if (!$is_ticket_filled) {
    unset($tickets[$k]);
}
```

Is causing the issue since unset does not reset the array indexes.
http://ideone.com/5q74Wv

Then later you iterate using `for($k=0; $k < count($tickets); $k++)`

You should instead rebase the array after using `unset($tickets[$k])`

```
if ($bets->type === 'simple') {
    //...
    $tickets = array_values($tickets);
 }
```

or check the existence of the ticket when iterating over indexes

```
$ticketCount = count($tickets);
for ($k=0; $k < $ticketCount; $k++) {
    if (false === isset($tickets[$k]) {
       continue;
    }
    //...
}
```

or easier still, iterate over the existing tickets array using `foreach` instead of `for`.

```
foreach ($tickets as $k => $ticket) {
   //...
}
```

Then change `$tickets[$k]` with just `$ticket` since `$k` is not used anywhere else.

Comment: Appearently only the foreach example worked perfectly! Thank you Sir!